# Shapely “parallel_offset” with distance in meters from Lat/Lon coordinates

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, shapely, matplotlib-basemap

I need to find a LineString at a distance in meters from a line with coordinates in Lat/Lon. I am trying this approach based on what i found in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697374/calculate-polygon-area-in-planar-units-e-g-square-meters-in-shapely

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
point1 = (8.83, 45.69)
point2 = (8.86, 45.71)
distance = 10000 #meters
m = Basemap(projection='sinu',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
xi_seg = LineString([m(point1[0],point1[1]),m(point2[0],point2[1])])
lcoords_s = xi_seg.parallel_offset(distance, 'left').coords[0]
lcoords_s_4326 = Point(m(lcoords_s[0],lcoords_s[1],inverse = True))
```

The resulting coordinates of the Point `lcoords_s_4326` are (45.75149569876954, 8.745680842264079). However, i checked on QGIS and the distance between `point1` and `lcoords_s_4326` is lower than 10'000 meters. Any thought on how to get a distance of 10'000 meters from one point to the other? I am working with data in every part of the planet and not just in this specific region